# Determine installed Microsoft Excel version using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache, excel, apache-poi

I need to determine which version of Microsoft Excel is installed on a Windows PC.  I'm working with Apache POI but can't figure out an easy way to do this.

Anyone know if Apache POI has a built in functionality to do this?  Any ideas how to do this using Java code?

Answer (score 4):

POI provides a mechanism for writing Excel documents without using any of the Excel APIs. I doubt it has a mechanism to detect the installed version, as it has no dependency on an installed version of Excel.

Following a pattern similar to the one described in [this question about detecting the Excel version in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858966/detecting-installed-excel-version-and-service-packs), you could use [JACOB](http://danadler.com/jacob/) to detect the installed Excel version like so:

```
ActiveXComponent xl = new ActiveXComponent("Excel.Application");
try {
    xl.getProperty("Version");
} finally {
    xl.invoke("Quit", new Variant[] {});
}
```

Comment: Now that's slick, +1! Being a Windows hater, I never think to use COM for this kind of stuff.

Comment: And congratulations on 1000 :)

Answer (score 3):

I really, really don't think POI has this functionality, as it's explicitly written to work cross-platform. It only deals with document files.

If I were faced with this task, I'd dig into the registry (via the Windows API) for the association of the `.XLS` file type. That will, err should give you a link to the most recently and completely installed Excel. Not reliably, because

- there might not *be* an Excel installed;
- the user might have changed the association; or
- the Excel pointed at by the association might be broken.

But given the hint of (usually) the applicable executable, you could then examine either the `.EXE` file header of Excel or perhaps something in the surrounding files to determine Excel's version.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it just occured to me that older Microsoft Excel versions have file extensions .xls and new ones have .xlsx.

I can just get reference to the file and get the file extensions... that easy.

If anyone has a better solution please let me know.

Comment: You do realize that it's possible for an older version of Excel to open, read and modify .xlsx documents using the compatibility pack here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924074